# How to disconnect from database in PSQL in Git-Bash?

Tags: sql, psql, git-bash

The database I would like to disconnect from is called library. I have tried the following which I found on https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/postgresql/reference/manual/12.2/ecpg-sql-disconnect.html:

DISCONNECT DATABASE library;

DISCONNECT library;

The error I receive:

```
postgres=# DICONNECT library;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DICONNECT"
LINE 1: DICONNECT library;
```

I know how to disconnect via a GUI, but how do you do it on the command line? Many resources online show how to connect to a database, but not how to disconnect.

Comment: The link to the manual is for embedded SQL in a C program, the reference for the `psql` command line tool is here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Are you trying to quit (exit) `psql`?

Comment: Thank you for this link! Still unable to find a disconnect command in the link? Initially, I was trying to drop a database using DROP DATABASE. This command works fine if I am not connected to a database, however if I am, I receive this error: "ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database."

Comment: If I connect to one of my databases named "postgres" and try to delete the database, "test", I now receive the error:  
postgres=# DROP DATABASE test;
ERROR:  database "test" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
postgres=#

Comment: However, if I right click on the test database in my GUI (pgAdmin) and click disconnect. I can then delete the database perfectly in the command line using DROP DATABASE. Shouldn't there be a disconnect command in the command line? Im new to psql and understand a lot of it, but the connecting/disconnecting concept is over my head :)